# Why is this function executing many times?

Tags: javascript, dom, addeventlistener

I am making a simple budget program and  I am having some trouble with refreshing the remain budget when I delete the items in the list. The function budgetDeleteItem executes many times and I don't know why. Maybe it has something to do with it beeing inside a for loop, but I don't know how to get it out of there and still make it work.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title></title>
  </head>
  <body>
<h1>Budget for the week</h1>
<form>

  <input id= "itemName" type="text" name="itemName" value="" placeholder="name of the item" >
  <input id = "itemCost" type="text" name="itemCost" value="" placeholder="cost of the item">

</form>
<button type="button" name="button"> Add new item </button>

   <ul>

   </ul>

  <p>total budget: <span id= "budget"> 100 </span> </p>

  </body>

  <script type="text/javascript">

const button= document.querySelector("button");
const ul= document.querySelector("ul");

button.addEventListener("click", checkEntry )

function checkEntry() {
  const itemName = document.getElementById("itemName").value;
  const itemCost = document.getElementById("itemCost").value;
  addItem(itemName, itemCost);
}

function addItem(itemName, itemCost){
  const li = document.createElement('li');
  li.innerHTML = ` <span class= "itemName">${itemName} </span>
    $ <span class=itemCost> ${itemCost} </span>
    <span class="delete"> X </span> `;
  ul.appendChild(li);
  deleteItem();
  budgetAddItem(itemCost);
}

function deleteItem(){
  const deleteButton = document.querySelectorAll(".delete");
  for (let i = 0; i < deleteButton.length; i++) {
    deleteButton[i].addEventListener("click", function(e) {
      if (e.target.classList.contains("delete")) {
        e.target.parentElement.remove();
        budgetDeleteItem(e);
      }
    })
 }
}
// Refreshes the remain budget whenever you add an Item
function budgetAddItem(itemCost){
const budgetContent = document.getElementById("budget").textContent;
const budgetContentParsed = parseInt(budgetContent);
const oldBudget = document.getElementById("budget");
const itemCostParsed = parseInt(itemCost);
const newBudget = budgetContentParsed - itemCostParsed;
oldBudget.innerHTML =`${newBudget}`;
}

// Refreshes the remain budget whenever you delete an Item
function budgetDeleteItem (e) {
const oldBudget = document.getElementById("budget");
const budgetContent = document.getElementById("budget").textContent;
const budgetContentParsed = parseInt(budgetContent);
const itemCost= e.target.parentElement.querySelector(".itemCost").textContent;
const itemCostParsed = parseInt(itemCost);
const newBudget = budgetContentParsed + itemCostParsed;
oldBudget.innerHTML =`${newBudget}`;
}




  </script>




</html>
```

Comment: You're calling `deleteItem()` every time you call `addItem()`, which is creating a new click event listener on every delete element every time.

Comment: And you think it would solve the problem to execute it just once, outside the AddItem()? would not i have the same problem because of the for loop?

Comment: OT, but your script is below `</body>`, which creates invalid HTML. Also `oldBudget.innerHTML =\`${newBudget}\`;` is nonsense, you can simply do `oldBudget.innerHTML = newBudget;`

Comment: Regarding the actual question, removing an item from the DOM works fine but keeps assigning click handlers to the other delete buttons. So the first delete button does what it's supposed to do, but the second one calls `budgetDeleteItem()` twice, etc. A better way is to separate content from presentation, i.e. keep an array of budget items and rebuild the HTML completely whenever it changes.

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned in the comments, you are creating duplicate bindings.  One possible way to do this is to provide a way to limit the elements you are adding new bindings to.  Consider...

```
<span class="delete new"> X </span>
```

If you create your elements with two classes, then you have an indicator to know which one(s) are new.  Then...

```
const deleteButton = document.querySelectorAll(".delete.new");
```

Select by both classes to get only the new ones.  Finally...

```
deleteButton[i].classList.remove('new');
```

To remove the new class, to keep it from being selected in the future.

Comment: I think I follow, but i think the problem was not located in removing items, that worked properly. The problem that i have is that the budget is not updating as it suppose to, whenever i errase an element

Comment: @petrushka_95 Ok, so it sounds like you are asking about multiple issues, where as I addressed the multiple execution issue which is detailed in the question subject and body.  If you are asking about a secondary issue, then that should be its own question, otherwise this question becomes too broad.

Comment: Sory if I wasn't clear enough. The function that I am having trouble with is budgetDeleteItem(). It executes whenever I errase an item and it refreshes the remain budget. The deletion of the items seems to be working fine